# Encryption functions in PHP output unexpected characters

Tags: php, cookies, mcrypt

I use `simple_encrypt` to store some sensitive information in the cookie. When I try to decrypt it with `simple_decrypt`, it doesn't give the same string. When I try to output that string after `simple_decrypt` I get chars with symbols like `�`. What's wrong?

```
$salt ='sososo222xxxXXsder3FVRE';
function simple_encrypt($text)
{
    global $salt;
    return mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $salt, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
}

function simple_decrypt($text)
{
    global $salt;
    return mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $salt, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
}
```

**EDIT:** 
I use `setcookie("rt", simple_encrypt($a['rt']), time()+(3600 * 24 * 365));` to store cookie. I also put `echo simple_encrypt($a['rt']);` before setcooking, and got the different value that it is in the cookie. That's just amazing...

Comment: I'm getting the same string on decrypt..

Comment: You got a different value? *What* different value? Different compared to *what* original value? It's impossible to debug something this vague.

Comment: It *sounds* like a difference in character sets. For example, if you're using UTF8, all the parts of the chain from client to server to database server to server to client to cookie and back must all use UTF8.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function simple_encrypt($text)
{
    global $salt;
    return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $salt, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
}

function simple_decrypt($text)
{
    global $salt;
    return base64_decode(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $salt, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
}
```

Comment: You need to use `base64_decode` in `simple_decrypt`, not `rtrim`.

Comment: see my updated answer but I don't know if this solve his problem

Comment: @userNOID: the decryption operations should come in the reverse order.  Even though you put on your socks before you put on your shoes, you need to take off your shoes *first*.

Comment: I think there is problem elsewhere because here your code works:
http://writecodeonline.com/php/
try it:
`$newtext = simple_encrypt('hello');
echo simple_decrypt($newtext);`

Comment: @DCoder I understood that, and changed it in the correct order, but I still get the same result. It doesn't work with a COOKIE...

Comment: Try calling urlencode() on your string before sending it to the cookie -- I seem to recall that PHP automatically does a urldecode() on the data when making it available in $_COOKIE.

Comment: @evening: the encryption/decryption part does work OK, if it doesn't work with a cookie you need to debug the cookie writing/reading logic. Are you doing decryption in the same request or a different one? The newly set value will not be magically placed inside `$_COOKIE` in the same request, only in the next one.